# SQL function to return a predefined value

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am overwriting functions in a procedure that are no longer used. I would like to replace some functions with a function that returns a predefined value such as string 'Not Found' no matter what argument the function is called. What is the best practice to do this? I am thinking something like this:

```
FUNCTION returnsamevalue(argument VARCHAR2)

RETURN VARCHAR2
AS
BEGIN
     RETURN 'Not Found';
END;
```

Comment: Seems OK to me - what concerns about this approach prompted you to ask this question?  What's the purpose of keeping the functions around if they're not doing what they were designed for / won't changing the output interfere with other functionality?  If they're no longer required, remove the functions and the code that calls them; unless there's good reason not to.

Comment: throw an error or an exception, or delete it